# Xorg сведет меня с ума(

Tags: linux, debian, xorg

Это опять я. дебиан 10, драйвер nouveau, карта 550ti. Внезапно, без каких либо на то причин, умирает изображение. Зависает и больше ничего не происходит. Вот ошибка

```
апр 17 17:44:10 Debian kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: control 2:0:0:PCM Playback Volume:0 is already present
апр 17 17:51:00 Debian kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: gr: TRAP ch 5 [021fac9000 Xorg[731]]
апр 17 17:51:00 Debian kernel: nouveau 0000:03:00.0: gr: GPC0/PROP trap: 00000080 [ZETA_STORAGE_TYPE_MISMATCH] x = 0, y = 216, format = 0
```

Тут несколько ошибок, но больше всего волнует именно nouveau. Ставил драйвер нвидиа 390хх. Тоже самое, ставил драйвер скаченный с официального сайта - без результатно... В винде все работает, ни тормозит ни зависает. Карту в винде гонял бубликом пару часов - да, греется, но работает стабильно и иправно...

После зависания к подключаюсь к компу по ssh, все робыть. При попытке перезапустить ксорг

```
sudo /etc/init.d/kdm stop
```

и ему подобные команды с перечнем служб, пишет что нет этих служб. Возмоно, чисто в теории предпологаю что перезапускать нужно из tty а по shh я подключаюсь к обчной консоле. Но это теория.

Comment: а хард жив ? такое может быть если хард отваливается)

Comment: @eri но по ssh подключаюсь и все роботает нормально, правда в консоле. Хард не проверял, но пробывал 2 разных жестких.

Comment: всё?) `ls -laR` запусти попробуй... проверим хотяб структуру каталогов

Comment: @eri пожалуйста. (файл){https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Guselnikov-Maks/sfml_up/master/list.txt}. Правда не уверен что это поможет)

Comment: файл не нужен - просто бывает зависает этот вывод

Comment: @eri я вывод команды в текстовый файл перенаправил ls -laR > list.txt я попробывал сделать вывод, он как показал все пути, и понял что скопировать не смогу, вот решил вывести в файл,.

Comment: зависло оно или нет - вот в чем вопрос)

Comment: @eri нет. Правда писалось секунд 10, но вывод в файл занял буквально секунд 5